# What is wrong with my determinant calculation?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   2 & 6 & 4 & 0  \\
   2 & 0 & 4 & 2  \\
   0 & 3 & 2 & 1  \\
   2 & 6 & 4 & 8  \\
\end{array}} \right| = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   2 & 6 & 4 & 0  \\
   0 & { - 6} & 0 & 2  \\
   0 & 3 & 2 & 1  \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 8  \\
\end{array}} \right| = 2\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   { - 6} & 0 & 2  \\
   3 & 2 & 1  \\
   0 & 0 & 8  \\
\end{array}} \right| = 2*8\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   { - 6} & 0  \\
   3 & 2  \\
\end{array}} \right| = 16*( - 12 - 0) =  - 192$$

> Correct answer: -96

Comment: Your calculation is correct. If you haven't copied the matrix wrongly or otherwise introduced a factor of $2$, the "correct" answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, the correct answer is $-192$. Verification:

```
sage: Matrix([[2,6,4,0],[2,0,4,2],[0,3,2,1],[2,6,4,8]]).det()
-192
```